# Deployment error Could not create a new instance of class [SearchableGrailsPlugin]!

Tags: tomcat, grails, war

I have been having this error for a while when I try to deploy my war file. I tried searching but nothing seemed to help. The war file works when I deploy on tomcat on a my system but when I deploy on another system I get this error:

```
    SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.NewInstanceCreationException: Could not create a new instance of class [SearchableGrailsPlugin]!
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.NewInstanceCreationException: Could not create a new instance of class [SearchableGrailsPlugin]!
```

Comment: What version of Grails are you using, and what version(s) of Tomcat and Java on the build and deployment systems?

Comment: Apache Tomcat/6.0.37 JVM Version 1.6.0_33-b05 Grails Version 1.3.5 for the deploypment system. (Windows 7 Machine). 
Apache Tomcat/6.0.37 JVM Version 1.7.0_03-b05 Grails Version 1.3.5 for the build system. (Ubuntu). 
Could this be the problem? I will check and get back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment suggests that you're using Java 7 on the build machine but Java 6 on the deployment machine.  This is probably the root of the problem, if you want to deploy on Java 6 then you need to build on Java 6 as well.

If this were plain Java you could get away with `-source 1.6 -target 1.6 -bootclasspath ...` options to the Java 7 javac, but in Grails this is somewhat hidden away in the build mechanism, by far the easiest approach is to build using a Java version no later than the one on which you will deploy (i.e. it's OK to build on 6 and deploy on 7 but not vice-versa).

Comment: Thanx a lot, it is working now. I feel stupid, anyway I'm a newbie in grails.